# javascript function that can be used to redirect to any url

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently doing a website and I use the following code to redirect the links in my website through an input button:

```
<div><input type='button' id='http://www.amazon.com' onclick='redirect(this)'></div><script type="text/javascript">
function redirect(element) { var parent =parent.elementNode; var content =parent.querySelector('input'); window.location.href=content.id </script>
```

I am a complete beginner at web programming and I would like to get feedback about it, since I haven't seen this done anywhere else, get pros and cons, and to know whether it is inefficient to redirect like this with javascript.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Why not use the `<a>` tag?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about the quality of working code are off-topic (but may be suitable for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)).

Comment: Yep. Using the `<a>` tag is the way to go. You don't need javascript for this. It's costy and makes your page heavier. Links should be added to the anchor tag. It's what it's used for.

Comment: as i said, i am a complete beginner, and i was just asking. Thanks  for the feedback guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THIS IS OVERKILL

No need for JavaScript

do:

```
<a href="link-to-site.com">Text</a>
```